# How to avoid entering visual mode when clicking a link while using evil?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, evil, mouse

Emacs newbie here using spacemacs. How to avoid entering visual mode when clicking a link while using evil? This is particularly problematic in org-mode.

[image: Clicking link enter Visual mode]

Comment: What happens if you click with the middle mouse button?

Comment: Using mac which has no middle mouse button.